# Como manter TextView centralizada no emulador?

Tags: android, textview

sou iniciante no desenvolvimento e estrou aprendendo a desenvolver para Android com o Android Studio 3.1.1. Em um dos exercícios que estou fazendo, é necessário recuperar qual checkbox foi marcada e exibir em uma textView, na interface eu centralizo o textView e rodo no emulador, quando eu clico no botão para mostrar o resultado ele não fica centralizado, como posso manter esse resultado centralizado na tela?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o codigo do layout aqui por favor

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver o textView estiver dentro de um LinearLayout pode atribuir para ele assim    **android:gravity="center"**    já ira centralizar o texto.

```
  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSeusEquipamentos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/selecionarPool"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolvi dessa maneira